# Magento 2 footer.store_switcher not working

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 Im trying to remove the store selector in the footer.

Im using this code line in default.xlm of my theme.

```
<referenceBlock name="footer.store_switcher" remove="true"/>
```

All other referenceBlock's are working fine.

But the Store selector is still placed in the footer.

Maybe my code is wrong or there is another way to do this.
Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it works for me.

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
   <referenceBlock name="store_switcher" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```